# sudo: password prompted even when NOPASSWD is set

Tags: linux-mint, sudo

```
~/bin$ cat setbrightness 
id
echo $1 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness

~/bin$ whoami
rag


~/bin$ sudo -l
Matching Defaults entries for rag on this host:
    env_reset, mail_badpass, secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin

User rag may run the following commands on this host:
    (root) NOPASSWD: /home/rag/bin/setbrightness
    (ALL : ALL) ALL
```

EDIT: /etc/sudoers

```
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    mail_badpass
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification
Cmnd_Alias   SETBRIGHTNESS = /home/rag/bin/setbrightness

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
rag ALL=NOPASSWD:SETBRIGHTNESS

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Run command

```
~/bin$ sudo /home/rag/bin/setbrightness 3000
[sudo] password for rag:
```

Can someone please point out why the password is prompted when running `sudo` for that command?

Comment: What does the actual sudoers file have in it? Perhaps it's an order thing, for some reason the (ALL:ALL) ALL is getting matched first?

Comment: i have now added /etc/sudoers

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It's the order - if I replicate your sudoers file with:

```
Cmnd_Alias   TESTCOMM = /bin/more
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
dave    ALL=NOPASSWD:TESTCOMM
%admin  ALL=(ALL) ALL
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

I get the same behaviour e.g. doing sudo more asks for a password, same as sudo .

However...

```
Cmnd_Alias   TESTCOMM = /bin/more
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
%admin  ALL=(ALL) ALL
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
dave    ALL=NOPASSWD:TESTCOMM
```

Let's me use more without a password, just prompting for anything else.

I guess this is due to the order which which things are checked in sudo (bottom-to-top).

Comment: yes, it seems to be the problem with order. I do not understand then why the file has this particular order of sections if it is problematic. is it particular to `linux mint`? the default order is `1. user privelege specification followed by 2. members of group sudo`

Comment: My test showing the difference was on Ubuntu 12.10 so it's not specific I think. What I don't know is if this is normal operation or a bug, but I would guess normal operation otherwise it would be being shouted from the rooftops.

Comment: later entries override previous ones, so the main sudo config file /etc/sudoers defines some global behaviour (admin group can do it all) and at last includes /etc/sudoers.d/ for custom stuff. if you couldn't override the prev entries then including /etc/sudoers.s/ wouldn't be as useful. the last rule wins, not the more specific one as you might expect.

Comment: @rag The reason that it specifies the user rules before the superuser rules (aka admin/wheel/sudo) is that if you are following the Rule of Least Privilege you should avoid using sudo/root as much as possible. Since `sudo` has become much more popular than `su root` a number of distributions are putting the first or sometimes all new users into the `admin/wheel/sudo` group which is what is causing the confusion. See my answer for a better way to do things.

Comment: Thank you so much. I browse about 20 different forums, before finding your working solution ♥

Comment: NB! Order applies also with `/etc/sudoers.d`. I added a file which alphabetically came below a `NOPASSWD` rule, thus overrode the exceptions. Giving the last file a name so it came _before_ work just like it should.

Answer (score 4):

How did you edit the sudoers file?  To verify a valid sudoers file ALWAYS use the `visudo` command and NEVER edit the sudoers file directly.  This looks to be one of those cases.

Comment: i edited using `visudo`. also you can see in `sudo -l` it displays the configuration as done through `visudo`